# steps to make a registry-safe copy of an MFC COM project

Tags: c++, mfc, registry

I have tried several times in the past to make, say, a branch copy of MFC code which has a COM TypeLib. It has always been a registry nightmare. But the need is still there in that I want to be able to use an ordinary configuration management tool like SVN to make a branch so software can be delivered and development in the trunk can continue. COM and the registry have a hard time doing this for many reasons. What is needed is a list of vetted best-practice steps hammered out on a forum like this. Is there already experience out there? If not, is anyone interested in working with me on this? I have a starter list of steps.

Comment: It's never been that clear to me why programmers consider this such an obstacle.  It is just configuration, that should never be a big deal.  If you are still using Regsvr32 then that's a strong hint that it high time that you consider creating an installer for the COM server.  Makes it just as easy on you as it does on your user.

Comment: I do use Advanced Installer. Are you suggesting I use it when I want to cut a branch for an MFC COM project?